# Facebook php sdk: How to delete a user after registration to my app

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I'm using the facebook php sdk to enable users signing into my web app using their facebook account. After a user tries to register using their facebook account, I'm retrieving their details using `Facebook.getSignedRequest();` and adding them to my DB.

My problem is in case an error is found during adding the new user to my DB, in which case I'm interested to roll back and delete them from my app **on facebook**.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the user can remove your App. Just check if he is in the database already when he returns.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of course I can make sure he won't be in the DB. My problem is that when the user hits the button `fb:login-button` he is redirected to the registration form only if he isn't registered to my app yet, otherwise the method defined for `on-login` is called, so in case he is registered but doesn't appear in the DB he won't have a chance to register again.