# Facebook php api: Verify user details according to my app's policy

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using the following form to allow users register to my web app through their facebook account. I have my own policy regarding Username's length, password's complexity etc. and I want to force it also on user that register through facebook, I know that I can do it in the register.php file (the Facebook php api: Verify user details according to my app's policy, see below) but then the user is already registered from facebook's perspective.

My question is, then, how can I prevent a user from being registered to my app without providing registration details which fit my app's policy?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'MY_FB_APP_ID',
        channelUrl : 'channel.html', 
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true, 
        oauth      : true, 
        xfbml      : true  
      });
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
      });
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        window.location.reload();
      });

    };
    (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; 
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); 
      js.id = id; 
      js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
  </script>

  <div class="fb-registration"
   data-fields='[{"name":"name"},
                 {"name":"birthday"},
                 {"name":"location"},
                 {"name":"gender"},
                 {"name":"email"},
                 {"name":"username","description":"Username","type":"text"},
                 {"name":"password"}]'
   data-redirect-uri= MY_DOMAIN . "register.php" >
  </div>
```

Comment: Does it matter that the user has granted your app permission but isn't actually registered on your site? Wouldn't any in-app activity check for registration on your site first?

Comment: @John, please have a look in my comment to the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501113/facebook-php-sdk-how-to-delete-a-user-after-registration-to-my-app/28501382#28501382). I have explained why it bothers me to have the user registered to my app from facebook perspective while not appearing in my DB.

Comment: The Registration plugin is outdated anyway, AFAIK it is not even officially supported by FB any more. You’d be better off just implementing your own registration, and using FB for login to your app only.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `DELETE` call to `/user/permissions`. Since this would make the user re-auth your app, I wouldn't do this as soon as the user tries to create an invalid registration on your site. Instead, depending on your complexity, issue the `DELETE` call when the user has left your registration page for good.

[According to the docs:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/permissions#delete)

> The second thing you can do is to completely de-authorize the app
>   making the delete call. Once this is done, anyone using your app will
>   have to go through the Facebook Login process as if they were a new
>   user. This can be effective when an explicit 'log out' function is
>   provided, or an option to delete in-app accounts

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which brings me to my question here: [How to delete a user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501113/facebook-php-sdk-how-to-delete-a-user-after-registration-to-my-app/28501382#28501382). Reading the doc, it seems that I have to use a combination of request-id_user-id in order to make the deletion, I couldn't find anywhere how do I get the request-id.

Comment: @Subway I haven't used FB Login in awhile, so I'm sorry I can't help you any further. I'd suggest re-reading the [Login docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2) and re-evaluating your login/registration flow. You should always be two things when a user wants to login to your app - check that they have authorized your app on FB, and that they have an account in your database.